# Why does .o files contain debug symbols but static library (.a) does not?

Tags: c++, macos, static-libraries, static-linking, debug-symbols

A static library (MacOS .a package) is made out of several object files (compiled source code .o files). From the Xcode output I can verify that .o files were built using debug symbols (-g flag used), moreover, running `dwarfdump file.o` prints out debug information. 
When all the object files are gathered together in a .a package `dwardump libname.a` returns nothing. Does this mean that debug symbols were stripped out on packaging stage? (which is achieved by invoking `libtool` with the flags: `-static -arch_only x86_64`)

If this is the case, how can I re-enable debug symbols in .a package?

Comment: They're probably still there; extract an object file from your library using `ar x` and check again.

Comment: yeap, they are. why can't I see them using dwarfdump or are there any special tools for libraries?

Comment: Because `dwarfdump` works on object files and a library archive is not an object file.  If you want to work on the objects inside an archive, extract them.